# Pthread readwrite lock issue

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

Please check the below code sample. It is clear that one thread can lock the object for a read lock and another thread can unlock it and then can get a write lock. The code for read write lock is [here](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/pkg/uclibc/libpthread/linuxthreads/rwlock.c%20here) (check the function __pthread_rwlock_unlock). My question is, why is this behavior is chosen? Basically any thread can unlock the "lock" when some threads already got read locks on the "lock". May be it is for performance considerations and programmers are trusted to do the right thing here. I am creating a distributed lock service and was going through pthread lock implementations.

```
 #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    pthread_rwlock_t       rwlock;
    void *fun(void *arg)
    {
      printf("Thread created\n");
      int rc = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
      if (rc == 0)
        printf("I unlcoked thread_id=%lu\n", (long unsigned int)pthread_self());
      rc = pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
      if (rc == 0)
        printf("got the rwlock write thread_id=%lu\n", (long unsigned int)pthread_self());

    }

    int main()
    {
      int rc;

      rc = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
      if (rc == 0)
      printf("Got read lock thread_id=%lu\n", (long unsigned int)pthread_self());

      sleep(2);
      pthread_t tid;
      pthread_create(&tid, 0, fun, 0);
      sleep(34);

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is basically to favour writers over readers to avoid writer starvation.

Answer (score 1):

It would be too expensive to keep a list of all threads that hold the read lock. Especially today when lots of code out there expects to be able to hold thousands, if not millions, of read locks. And locks are expected to be very fast.

POSIX itself says that the behavior of unlocking a lock that the thread calling `pthread_rwlock_unlock` didn't obtain is undefined. So technically your code it wrong, but I don't think anyone out there bothers to catch this error unless you're running in some heavy and slow debugging mode.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think this approach works fine for in process locks. For distributed locking system, this approach will not be suitable.

Comment: Yes @NipunTalukdar the results are undefined, if the calling thread doesn't hold the lock. MUTEX or Conditional Variables are good synchronization and/or IPC mechanisms to deal with critical sections (lock/unlock) over multi threaded environment.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply using the lock incorrectly.  It's undefined behaviour for a thread to unlock a lock which it doesn't currently hold.

Comment: Actually, the read-write locks (as implemented in pthread library) has the behavior : 1. if it is write locked, only lock owner thread  can unlock. If other threads try to unlock, they get EPERM error.  2. If it is read locked, any thread can "unlock" it. Unlocking a read lock translates to decrementing a count. If the count is zero and some threads still try to unlock it, EPERM error again.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar: That's just a quirk of the implementation - you're still breaking the contract, so it's allowed to do anything at all (including decrement the use count).  I think I misunderstood your question though - if you're wondering why this error case isn't specifically checked for and handled, it's because you can't keep a list of the owning threads while using a bounded amount of space.